# Como publicar aplicação feitas em Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Bom, sou novo com Node.js, consegui montar uma aplicação de exemplo, aprendi bastante coisa do Node com Express, mas não consigo entender como publicar a aplicação no servidor linux.
Alguem sabe como publicar? Eu teria que criar um processo pra ele rodar automaticamente o comando `node app.js` ?

Obs: O Servidor tem o node instalado.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Há algumas maneiras. As que eu conheço são:

- Usando o package `forever`: https://www.npmjs.org/package/forever
- Usando o `supervisord` + `nodemon`

  - `supervisord`: http://supervisord.org/ (não é package do Node.js)
  - `nodemon`: https://www.npmjs.org/package/nodemon

Basta enviar os arquivos para o servidor, configurar o `Express` para servir numa porta acessível e executar seu `server.js` utilizando um dos packages acima.

Se for necessário redirecionar a porta, utilize o `nginx`: http://nginx.org/en/download.html

Answer (score 3):

você vai precisar criar um script de start do serviço utilizando os pacotes citados pelo @Cigano

```
#!/bin/bash
JSHOME=/opt/homeapp #home de suas apps..
DIR=$JSHOME/js/ #diretorio dos apps
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin #caso tenha o node fora do path padrão
NODE_PATH=$JSHOME/node_modules #path com pacotes para seu app questão de isolamento
# no final ficaria algo como
# app em /opt/homeapp/js/appfile.js
# nodepath como /opt/homeapp/js/node_modules
NODE=node
NODE_ENV=production
APP="appfile"
test -x `which $NODE` || exit 0
function start_app {
        ###note que NODE_ENV e NODE_PATH são variaveis definidas para o ambiente de execução do nohup
        # o | cronolog é opcional... fiz para registrar logs por data.. cronolog é velho não use se não precisar
        NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV nohup $NODE $DIR/${APP}.js | /usr/sbin/cronolog $DIR/log/%Y/%m/%d/${APP}.log 2>&1 &
        echo $! > "$DIR/${APP}.pid"
}
function stop_app {
        killall node > /dev/null 2>&1
        echo ok
}
case $1 in
        start)
                start_app 
        ;;
        stop)
                stop_app
        ;;
        restart)
                stop_app
                start_app
        ;;
        *)
                echo "usage: render-image {start|stop}" ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Você só precisa adicionar esse trecho de código ao seu `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
}
```

Você pode adicionar inúmeros comandos que são executados em vários momentos do ciclo de vida de seu pacote. Para mais detalhes você pode dar uma olhada nesse [link](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-scripts.html) onde tem toda a especificação.

Por padrão o servidor espera encontrar um arquivo `server.js` na raiz do projeto, como no seu caso o arquivo que precisa executar é o `app.js` você precisa especificá-lo.

Abaixo um exemplo de um `package.json` simples que servirá p/ você.

```
{
    "name": "[NOME DA SUA APLICAÇÃO]",
    "version": "[VERSÃO]",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node app.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "~3.4.8"
    }
}
```

Caso ainda sua aplicação esteja funcionando localmente e no seu servidor não, é bem provável que a porta que você está informando não seja a especificada pelo servidor. Por exemplo eu utilizo como servidor o **AppFog**, e a porta que deve ser utilizada pela aplicação é informada através de uma variável de ambiente `process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT`.

Na minha aplicação fica mais ou menos dessa forma:

```
app.set("port", process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000);
...
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get("port"));
```